Are mezzanine and loft interchangeable in American English and Canadian English? If not, what's the difference?
Ok, so I have tried to get to the bottom of all this but I ended up even more confused. According to Cambridge Dictionary, the structure I have put a circle around is a mezzanine because the dictionary has a picture of a very similar structure in its mezzanine entry.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mezzanine
It's the first sense.
I also watched a couple of video hoping that that would demystify things but unfortunately, that wasn't the case.
Many people in the YouTube videos I watched sometimes referred to the structure as a loft or as a mezzanine or as a bed loft or sleeping loft.


If you are only interested in American and Canadian English, you should prefer prevalently American English dictionaries such as Merriam-Webster, American Heritage, Canadian Oxford Dictionary (no online version) and a Guide to Canadian English Usage but its search tool is useless for looking up words. You know, in British English dictionaries such as Cambridge and Collins, to name but two, they will also list the AmEng and CanEng equivalents too.

Mezzanine in AmE refers to a floor of a building.  Sometimes when you get on a high-rise elevator, there will be a button that takes you to the Mezzanine.

From Cambridge Dic. Loft (U.S.) an upper floor or room. An apartment in a large building that was previously used for industry. Examples: There are rats in our loft. and
We are planning to convert our loft into an office. Do you think that could be done in the image you shared? Doesn't it suggest that a loft is usually much more spacious than a mezzanine?

A mezzanine is a space that is created between the floor and ceiling. It can have a variety of purposes. Generally used in buildings with high ceilings, they provide additional storage, work areas, or even office space. //
This additional level usually does not span the entire floor, but instead provides a sort of gallery from which you can look out over the entire space … https://pwiworks.com/mezzanine-vs-loft-whats-the-difference/

A loft in American English has an older meaning (e.g. a hay loft) which is a raised floor in a taller building (like your bedroom loft) or it can refer to a former factory floor level which has been turned into apartments that can have such lofts. A loft apartment

@Mari-LouA That is not how mezzanine is used in AmE.

@TimR The source I quoted is American, the company's address is 7930 W 1000 N
Nappanee, IN (Indiana) 46550 Go and tell them you know better than they do.

A lot can happen on the internet in a very short amount of time that can give a very distorted view of how words are used.  If Mezzanine is being used of sleeping lofts, that is a very recent phenomenon; probably 80% of AmE speakers would have no idea what you were talking about if you told them you put your bed on the Mezzanine.  It is an architectural term not used by much of the general public.  99% of AmE speakers would call it a "sleeping loft".

Ok. Thanks for the contributions but it's still not clear.

The purpose of language is to communicate. Decide who you want to communicate with. Use words they will understand.  Perhaps the term Mezzanine is used by real estate brokers in major US cities and has in recent years superseded "sleeping loft". It might be understood in Brooklyn but not in Podunk.  What is the purpose of your question? What real-world context do you need to use this word in?

So it seems that some people call it a loft and others call it a mezzanine. There often isn't one categorical definition in English.

As for context, both in informal and formal contexts. So are they interchangeable among laypeople then?

A loft is really the space under/inside the roof, above the habitable floors, and a mezzanine is built part way betwen main floors. It's a mezzanine, but everyone knows what a sleeping loft is.

But then what would you call the structure in the picture? A loft?

It's a sleeping loft, or a mezzanine sleeping area.

So the terms are used interchangeably then?

What about Australian English, New Zealand English, Nigerian English, South African English. etc. etc.? A loft is a permanent part of a room. A mezzanine can be an architectural feature OR  you can buy one and install it in a large space, like a commercial garage. I doubt there is any difference between Canadian and American English here. These kinds of terms are not different, unlike the legal area. That's where there can be considerable difference.

People often install or build a loft in rooms, like the one in your picture to get more out of their space. Those lofts in apartments are not called mezzanines. Some modern architects also build them into what otherwise would be quite small apartments.

From American Heritage Dictionary
Loft

1.
a. A large, usually unpartitioned floor over a factory, warehouse, or other commercial or industrial space.
b. Such a floor converted into an apartment or artist's studio.
2.
a. A partial floor occupying part of the space below the ceiling of a larger, high-ceilinged room.
b. A garret.
3. A gallery or balcony, as in a church.
4. A hayloft.

mezzanine

1. A partial story between two main stories of a building.
2. The lowest balcony in a theater or the first few rows of that balcony.

From the definition above we can deduce that a mezzanine will not usually cover the entire floor this best matches the image in the OP's post.
However…
In the US, a mezzanine appears to be restricted for industrial use. It is a semi-permanent platform created to increase storage space


A mezzanine is a self-supporting steel construction that is built between two floors and can consist of several floors. Various terms are used for a mezzanine, including mezz, or intermediate floor.

Source: https://www.profielnorm-usa.com

@Weather Vane There's also definition 1(a) which says it is an unpartitioned floor, which I surmise is an extended area without walls, and (b) sometimes converted into an apartment or studio. Does it mean that a loft is interchangeable with mezzanine? I'm not American, but in my British dialect I would not say the image in the OP's question is a loft. For me, a loft is similar to an attic, the headspace can either be generous or very low. You primarily use that space for storing old unused things. Some people convert their lofts into a spare bedroom, some into an office.

Oh, I had deleted the comment written when I thought that you were announcing 'loft' as the answer. It's not a loft per se, but if people are calling it a sleeping loft, that's what it is (as well as being a mezzanine).

@WeatherVane you should post your comment as the answer. It seems that a number of American speakers (and maybe also British) will describe the image in the OP's post as a sleeping loft. So be it.

It's aleady in your quoted definitions for 'loft': A partial floor occupying part of the space below the ceiling of a larger, high-ceilinged room. Perhaps some people are averse to using hoity-toity sounding terms like 'mezzanine'.

FWIW, "mezzanine" suggests to me a large, public building like a playhouse, sports stadium, or skyscraper. To describe something in a small personal apartment as a mezzanine sounds quite strange to me (American).

"Mezzanine" is definitely not limited to industrial use in the US.  In addition to the performance and assembly venues mentioned by @NuclearHoagie, I've seen it in commercial and institutional  settings, though rarely if ever in residential. N.b.: The linked industrial mezzanine website is from a Netherlands-based company exporting to the US.

Recently, (past 20 years?), you can purchase and install mezzanines (modular). However, in architecture, they are not modular; they are part-and-parcel of a structure. As Theodore says. I upvoted this answer.
